# draw inflated layout xml on an bitmap

Tags: android

I created a layout xml file that contains an extended textview.
What I want is to draw the textview in a bitmap.
What do I have to do after inflating the view so that I can use the draw method on the my canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are the steps to perform what you want:

1. You have to create a mutable Bitmap (with the size of the screen).
2. Create a Canvas from that Bitmap.
3. inflate your view, get a reference to it.
4. Call your_view.draw(your_canvas).

That's all, in your Bitmap you will have your view and all of it children drawn.

Comment: You also need to call layout.measure() and layout.layout() before rendering to a bitmap.