# Create bitmap of layout that is off-screen

Tags: android, bitmap, layout-inflater

I have to get a bitmap of a layout(say second screen) **Before** (can say without) bring it to the foreground screen. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240967/draw-inflated-layout-xml-on-an-bitmap) post. I am doing mistake somewhere in inflating the view.
Note:

```
1. Must not show the inflated screen (second screen)
2. Must not attach it to the parent view
```

My code snippet is here:

```
private Bitmap renderNextScreen() {
    
    // Getting width, height device
    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    
    Log.i(TAG, "Width- " + width+" Height - "+height);

    // Create a mutable bitmap
    Bitmap secondScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    
    // Created a canvas using the bitmap
    Canvas c = new Canvas(secondScreen);
    
    // Inflated the second screen
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondscreen, null);
    
    Log.i(TAG, "secondView.Height- "+secondView.getHeight()+" , secondView.Width " + secondView.getWidth());
    // Drawn the inflated view to canvas
    secondView.draw(c);
    
    preview.setImageBitmap(secondPage); // preview is the Imageview inside first screen
    return secondScreen;
}
```

My Log for height, width:

```
01-28 02:12:35.926: I/FirstActivity(21831): Width- 480 Height - 800
01-28 02:30:08.287: I/FirstActivity(22207): secondView.Height- 0 , secondView.Width 0
```

My preview was always blank. Thank you.

Comment: You can ask me for clarification :) I think I am doing mistake in inflating view....

Comment: Have you tried debugging width and height ? If I remember well, these two variables equals 0 when retrieved this way...

Comment: @Sephy you are right Actually I printed the bitmap's height and width.height and width of secondView is 0,0. But if I mention viewgroup in inflating the view It will come forth in screen... How can I get bitmap with my requirements...

Answer (score 2):

I think that changing:

```
View secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondscreen, null);
```

to:

```
View secondView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondscreen, null, false);
```

you will then need to declare layout params for the inflated view, somthing like:

```
secondView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(displaymetrics.widthPixels, 
displaymetrics.heightPixels/3));
```

Displaymetrics was a variable that held the dimension of the phones screen.

Then you should be able to turn that view into a bmp.